# Elements don't appear on the screen during API request

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I'm making an app which should show GIFs from Giphy API on the first screen and after clicking on certain GIF the second fragment should open and show GIF in full size.
But after I launch an app I see just empty screen (start_activity.xml) and none of GIFs is represented.
Links like API key, base URL and so on are correct.

```
class StartFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentStartBinding
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var adapter: StartAdapter
    private lateinit var viewModel: StartViewModel

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentStartBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[StartViewModel::class.java]
        recyclerView = binding.rvStart
        val gifs = mutableListOf<DataObject>()
        adapter = StartAdapter(gifs)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2)

        viewModel.myGifList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { gifList ->
            gifs.clear()
            gifs.addAll(gifList)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.getGif()
        }

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(object : StartAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
            override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
                val selectedGifUrl = gifs[position].image.origImage.url
                val bundle = Bundle()
                bundle.putString("selectedGifUrl", selectedGifUrl)

                Navigation.findNavController(binding.root)
                    .navigate(R.id.action_startFragment_to_detailFragment, bundle)
            }
        })

        return binding.root
    }
```

```
class StartAdapter(private val gifs: List<DataObject>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<StartAdapter.StartViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var mListener: OnItemClickListener

    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(position: Int)
    }

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: OnItemClickListener) {
        mListener = listener
    }

    class StartViewHolder(val binding: ItemGifLayoutBinding, listener: OnItemClickListener) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                listener.onItemClick(adapterPosition)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): StartViewHolder {
        val binding =
            ItemGifLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return StartViewHolder(binding, mListener)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return gifs.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: StartViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val data = gifs[position]
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context)
            .load(data.image.origImage.url)
            .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
                override fun onLoadFailed(
                    e: GlideException?,
                    model: Any?,
                    target: Target<Drawable>?,
                    isFirstResource: Boolean
                ): Boolean {

                    return false
                }

                override fun onResourceReady(
                    resource: Drawable?,
                    model: Any?,
                    target: Target<Drawable>?,
                    dataSource: DataSource?,
                    isFirstResource: Boolean
                ): Boolean {

                    return false
                }
            })
            .into(holder.binding.ivGif)
    }}
```

```
class StartViewModel: ViewModel() {

    private val repository = Repository()
    private val _myGifList = MutableLiveData<List<DataObject>>()
    val myGifList: LiveData<List<DataObject>> get() = _myGifList

    fun getGif() {
        try {
            val response = repository.getGifs().execute()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                _myGifList.postValue(response.body()?.res ?: emptyList())
            } else {

            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {

        }
    }
}
```

```
interface ApiService {

    @GET("v1/gifs/trending?api_key=*here is my API key located*")
    fun getGif(): retrofit2.Call<DataResult>
}
```

```
object RetrofitInstance {

    private val retrofit by lazy {
        Retrofit.Builder().
            baseUrl("https://api.giphy.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    val api: ApiService by lazy {
        retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

```
class Repository {

    fun getGifs(): retrofit2.Call<DataResult> {
        return RetrofitInstance.api.getGif()
    }
}
```

I know it can be a silly question, but I have no more ideas what is wrong with code.

As I mentioned, links to API is fully correct, so maybe its implementation in fragments is wrong.
Also can be ViewModel issue.

Comment: Did you verify that you get a response from the Giphy API? You can use either a debugger or a `Log.d()` statement, then check your Matlog panel in Android Studio.